# Formik and Yup, validating array field and also contents of array field

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I have a field in my yup schema that is defined like this:

`choices: array().min(2, 'At least two choices must be provided').of(number('Must be an integer').integer('Must be an integer').required('May not be empty')),`

Which, in English, should be:

- The field may be empty
- If it is not empty, it must contain at least two elements
- If an element is provided, it is required to be a non-empty string

The issue I'm facing is in Formik's `errors` object. This object has the same structure as the values of the form, but this means that `errors.choices` is either a string (complaining that the array as a whole fails validation because it is not long enough), or an array (complaining that an individual element fails validation). The problem is that which one it is seems to be quite unpredictable.

For example, if I add a single choice, that is an empty string, should I expect yup/formik to complain that the array is invalid, or that the field is invalid? `errors.choices` cannot be both an array and a string. What is the best practice way of dealing with this?